# Conditional sum statement/group by in (PROC) SQL on SAS

Tags: sql, if-statement, sas, conditional-statements, proc-sql

I am working in `SAS` using `(PROC) SQL` and I have the following data set:

```
ID          Date      Time    Delta_Time
 x    01/01/2019    121500             0            
 x    01/01/2019    121630           130
 x    01/01/2019    122005           375 
 x    01/01/2019    154745         32740
 x    01/01/2019    155905          1160
 y    01/04/2019    132356             0
```

In this example, ID `x` performs 5 actions on `01/01/2019`. What I would like to know is for how long each ID has been performing succeeding actions as long as `Delta_Time` does not exceed a certain value, e.g. `1500`. For this example, the result should thus look like:

```
ID          Date      Time  
 x    01/01/2019       505
 x    01/01/2019      1160
 Y    01/04/2019         0
```

I have a basic understanding of `SQL` but am new to `do loops`, `data steps` and `if statements`.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: What should the result be if all the delta_time of a ID,DATE are greater than your threshhold ? Not present in result, Zero (0), Miissing (.), something else

Answer (score 2):

The produces the output you say you want.  It would be nice to have more example data.

```
data t;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input id:$1. date:mmddyy. time delta;
   format date mmddyy.;
   datalines;
ID          Date      Time    Delta_Time
 x    01/01/2019    121500             0            
 x    01/01/2019    121630           130
 x    01/01/2019    122005           375 
 x    01/01/2019    154745         32740
 x    01/01/2019    155905          1160
 y    01/04/2019    132356             0
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data t;
   set t;
   by id date;
   delta_time=delta;
   if first.date then g=0;
   if delta gt 1500 then do;
      g+1;
      delta_time=.;
      end;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc means n sum;
   class id date g;
   var delta_time;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `first.id`? or `by id date;`?

Comment: I need to add date to BY.  I'm pretty sure the that is what OP meant.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `group by`:

```
proc sql;
    select id, date, sum(time)
    from t
    group by id, date;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full data step approach instead.

You do not need loops, a data step has a built in loop, so it's more understanding the logic of the data step loop and the IF statements.

Code and solution commented below - I'm actually not sure this will work, in all circumstances, particularly for the last record but it fits the shown use cases. If it doesn't work, please expand your sample data to include more relevant use cases.

```
data have;
    infile cards;
    informat ID $1. Date mmddyy10. Time 8. Delta_Time 8.;
    format ID $1. Date mmddyy10. Time 8. Delta_Time 8.;
    input ID   $       Date Time Delta_Time;
    cards;
 x    01/01/2019    121500             0            
 x    01/01/2019    121630           130
 x    01/01/2019    122005           375 
 x    01/01/2019    154745         32740
 x    01/01/2019    155905          1160
 y    01/04/2019    132356             0
 ;;;;
run;


*WANT is output data set created;
data want;
    *Have is input data set provided (above);
    set have;
    by ID date;
    
    *values you want to hold across rows;
    retain running_total ;

    *for the first of every date (within ID) set the running_total to 0;
    if first.date then
        running_total=0;


     *If the value is gratehr than 1500 and not the first record then do the following;
    if delta_time > 1500 & not first.Date  then
        do;
            *write a line to new data set with previous running_total value;
            output;
            *reset running_total;
            running_total=0;
        end;
    else /*continue to carry sum down otherwise*/
        running_total=sum(running_total, delta_time);
    
    *if you are on the last id, and value is less than 1500 you need to output it;
    if last.Id and delta_time < 1500 then output;
    
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

**DATA + SQL approach**

You can use a `DATA` Step to create a view containing a computed *synthetic* group based on your threshold criteria.  Use the view in SQL for quick and easy understanding.  This approach has been demonstrated many times in previous questions by myself and @Tom.

Example:

The computed group value is placed in variable named **section** in order to prevent possible incorrect assumptions by novice coders.
I like to add the count of the values going into the sum as well.

```
data have;
  infile cards;
  attrib
    id   length=$1 
    date informat=mmddyy10. format=mmddyy10.
  ; input 
ID  Date        Time   Delta_Time; cards;
 x  01/01/2019  121500      0
 x  01/01/2019  121630    130
 x  01/01/2019  122005    375 
 x  01/01/2019  154745  32740
 x  01/01/2019  155905   1160
 y  01/04/2019  132356      0
;


data have_sections / view=have_sections;
  set have;
  by id date;
  if first.date then section+1;
  if delta_time > 1500 then do;
    section+1;
    delete;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want(drop=section) as 
  select id, date, section
  , sum(delta_time) as section_total_time
  , count(*) as section_row_count
  from have_sections
  group by id, date, section
  order by id, date, section
  ;
```

The view

[image]

The final result

[image]

---

**DOW loop approach**

Loop over each `ID` `DATE` group and conditionally output segments within when the threshold is exceeded.

```
data want;
  do until (last.date);
    set have;
    by id date;
    if delta_time > 1500 then do;
      if not missing(sum) then output;
      call missing(sum,count);
    end; 
    else do;
      sum = SUM(sum, delta_time);
      count = SUM(count, 1);
    end;

  end;
  if not missing(sum) then output;
run;
```